# javafxports image pixelated when zoomed in imageview

Tags: java, android, gluon-mobile, javafxports

This is my code:

```
Image image1 = new Image(url);
Dialog mainDialog = new Dialog(true);

ImageView imageView = new ImageView();
imageView.setImage(image1);
imageView.setPreserveRatio(true);
imageView.setCache(true);
imageView.setSmooth(true);
imageView.setPickOnBounds(true);
imageView.setOnZoom(evt->{
    imageView.setScaleX(imageView.getScaleX()*evt.getZoomFactor());
    imageView.setScaleY(imageView.getScaleY()*evt.getZoomFactor());
});

mainDialog.setContent(imageView);
Platform.runLater(() -> mainDialog.showAndWait());
```

Comment: If your question is that you get a pixelated image, can you edit your question and post the initial size of your image, and also if the same happens on Desktop?

Comment: Image width is 380 and height 937.00. It doesn't happen on desktop

Answer (score 0):

You don't provide much information about the image quality, and what do you mean by pixelated, at what scale it happens, or if it is only on mobile and not on desktop.

Anyway, here are a few hints to improve the results.

- Add a hint to the cache, in this case `CacheHint.SCALE`.
- Add clipping to the imageView. If the scale is too big, the image will be big on memory. This will prevent a possible memory issue. Bind the size of the rectangle to the view dimensions.

This works fine for me, even with scale factors of 20+:

```
Image image1 = new Image(url); 
Dialog mainDialog = new Dialog(true);
ImageView imageView = new ImageView();
imageView.setImage(image1);
imageView.setPreserveRatio(true);
imageView.setCache(true);
imageView.setCacheHint(CacheHint.SCALE); // <-- hint
imageView.setSmooth(true);
imageView.setPickOnBounds(true);
imageView.setOnZoom(evt -> {
    imageView.setScaleX(imageView.getScaleX() * evt.getZoomFactor());
    imageView.setScaleY(imageView.getScaleY() * evt.getZoomFactor());
});
Rectangle r = new Rectangle();
imageView.setClip(r);    // <-- clip
r.widthProperty().bind(view.widthProperty());
r.heightProperty().bind(view.heightProperty());
mainDialog.setContent(imageView);
mainDialog.showAndWait();    // <-- No need of runLater
```